# Vue3 composition API import Components from 3rd party library not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to import a component from a 3rd Party API into my vue 3 project but I can not make it to run cause it says no unused vars. It worked in vue2 when I added it to the components property, but since the html tag is written differently as the import it is not working with V3.

how to deal with such cases in vue3 composition API?

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { reactive, ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import TradingVue from "trading-vue-js";      //trying to get this imported
type Stream = { market: string; timeframe: string };
let state = reactive({
  streams: <Stream[]>[],
  data: {
    ohlcv: [
      [1551128400000, 33, 37.1, 14, 14, 196],
      [1551132000000, 13.7, 30, 6.6, 30, 206],
      [1551135600000, 29.9, 33, 21.3, 21.8, 74],
      [1551139200000, 21.7, 25.9, 18, 24, 140],
      [1551142800000, 24.1, 24.1, 24, 24.1, 29],
    ],
  },
});

async function getOHLCV() {
  const response = await (
    await fetch(
      "http://localhost:3000/stream/ohlcv/" +
        state.streams[0].market +
        "/" +
        state.streams[0].timeframe
    )
  ).json();
}
onMounted(async function () {
  const response = await (await fetch("http://localhost:3000/stream")).json();
  state.streams = response;
  await getOHLCV();
});
</script>

<template><trading-vue :data="state.data.ohlcv"></trading-vue></template>
```

Comment: What you have is an ESlint error. What exactly is unused in the error? Either comment that one or use it somewhere in your code. Or disable/set the rule as a earning in your ESlint config file.

Comment: Linter errors don't affect how code works, unless they reveal an actual mistake, which may or not be the case. It's the case here. TradingVue isn't used anywhere, so you don't actually use this library. You can't use it at all because it's for Vue 2. V2 libs are not compatible with V3, unless they were specifically designed this way, this is explicitly mentioned in their docs.

Comment: I fixed the error with the eslint config file but now I get another error in the console
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:40 [Vue warn]: Property "$createElement" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance which seems to be related to the imported component

Comment: The error itself is quite explanatory. You do have a `$createElement` out of nowhere here. Also, if you don't update your question it will be hard helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, the library is not maintained, it's stated on the repo itself

> TradingVue.js was a hackable charting lib for traders. You could draw literally ANYTHING on top of candlestick charts. [Not Maintained]

So yeah, if you have some issues with Vue3, it is not even [a surprise](https://github.com/tvjsx/trading-vue-js/issues/278).

The issues that you face currently are not directly related to the package itself, but that package is not a good idea overall. Give a try to [those alternatives](https://github.com/tvjsx/trading-vue-js/issues/256) rather.

Or give a try to this [charts sections](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#charts). No need to spend more time on that package since it's not maintained IMO.

Comment: yea, I guess you are right. Seems like its not working with V3